# Using Service in a DTO?

Tags: nestjs

I have a DTO which handles the ResponseError or ResponseSuccess. It is defined as below :

```js
export class ResponseError implements ResponseFormatter {
  constructor(infoMessage: string, data?: any, errCode?: number) {
    this.success = false;
    this.message = infoMessage;
    this.data = data;
    this.errCode = errCode;
    Logger.warn(
      `${new Date().toString() 
        } - [Response]: ${ 
        infoMessage 
        }${data ? ` - ${  JSON.stringify(data)}` : ''}`,
    );
  }

  message: string;

  data: any[];

  errorMessage: any;

  error: any;

  success: boolean;

  errCode: number;
}
```

ResponseFormatter is an interface as below:

```js
export class ResponseError implements ResponseFormatter {
  constructor(infoMessage: string, data?: any, errCode?: number) {
    this.success = false;
    this.message = infoMessage;
    this.data = data;
    this.errCode = errCode;
    Logger.warn(
      `${new Date().toString() 
        } - [Response]: ${ 
        infoMessage 
        }${data ? ` - ${  JSON.stringify(data)}` : ''}`,
    );
  }

  message: string;

  data: any[];

  errorMessage: any;

  error: any;

  success: boolean;

  errCode: number;
}
```

And in services i am throwing my errors like

```js
      return new ResponseError(MESSAGES.BUILDINGS.NOT_FOUND, response);
```

Now as this app is growing i want to implement internalization so using i18n npm package. I know how to use it but the problem is how do i get it's service in this ResponseErrorDto ??
or is there any better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get a service inside of a DTO, you'd need to pass the service to the DTO's constructor. DTOs generally should be contracts rather than implementation in my opinion. That means they should define the shape of the object (via class properties) but it should not have any class specific methods. It may be that an [interceptor](https://docs.nestjs.com/interceptors) is more appropriate here, as you can have the interceptor inject the i18n service and make use of it across the entire application